# JSON parsing. String as Json array of objects

Tags: java, arrays, json, parsing

The given complete question is, just to clear up any issues:

```
   /**
 * q1: Write a public class named ColonialFive with private instance variables named "fly" of 
 * type boolean, "blond" of type int, "tragic" of type boolean, and "top" of type String.
 * 
 * Then write a public method inside the Problem Set class named "parseColonialFive" that 
 * takes a String as a parameter and returns an ArrayList of ColonialFive. This method will 
 * parse the input String as a properly formatted Json array of objects where each object 
 * represents the values for the instance of ColonialFive where the keys of each Json object 
 * are the instance variable names and the values are the values to which they should be set. 
 * Return an ArrayList of instances of ColonialFive with the instance variables matching the 
 * values from the Json objects. The order of instances in the ArrayList must match the order 
 * of objects in the Json array
 */
```

The code I have is:

```
    public class ColonialFive {
    private boolean fly;
    private int blond;
    private boolean tragic;
    private String top;

    public ColonialFive(boolean a, int b, boolean c, String d) {
        this.fly = a;
        this.blond = b;
        this.tragic = c;
        this.top = d;
    }
    public void setFly(boolean a) {
        this.fly = a;
    }
    public void setBlond(int b) {
        this.blond = b;
    }
    public void setTragic(boolean c) {
        this.tragic = c;
    }
    public void setTop(String d) {
        this.top = d;
    }

}

public ArrayList<ColonialFive> parseColonialFive(String a1) {
ArrayList<ColonialFive> data = new ArrayList<ColonialFive>();
JsonValue jsonValue = Json.parse(a1);
JsonArray jsonArray = jsonValue.asArray();

for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.size();i++) {              

    JsonObject thisAble = jsonArray.get(0).asObject();
        boolean a = thisAble.get("fly").asBoolean();

        JsonObject jsonObject2 = jsonArray.get(1).asObject();
        int b = jsonObject2.get("blond").asInt();

        JsonObject civ = jsonArray.get(2).asObject();
        boolean c = civ.get("tragic").asBoolean();

        JsonObject pri = jsonArray.get(3).asObject();
        String d =pri.get("top").asString();

        ColonialFive h = new ColonialFive(a,b,c,d);
        h.setFly(a);
        h.setBlond(b);
        h.setTragic(c);
        h.setTop(d);
        data.add(h);
}
return data;
}
```

When I run the code I do not get correct values for each instant variable. I am not sure what could be going wrong, I have tried to write this code several different ways as well.

I am not sure if I should be using JsonValue or not, it should work as is and others have even told me so

Comment: Why are you extracting the different values from different objects in the array? The input is supposed to be something like `[{"fly": true, "blond": 42, "tragic": false, "top": "Foo"}]` where all 4 values are keys of the same object in the array. The fact that you don't use `i` for anything inside the loop should be an instant mental alert, telling you something is wrong with the code.

Comment: one of my TA's told me to add the for loop. I realized it did nothing, but without the for loop I still got the question wrong

Comment: Of course you need a loop. You're supposed to read an array of unknown size, and return an `ArrayList` of all the parsed objects.

Comment: Wow that was so simple. Stupidest mistake. All I had to do was change 0 to i, then delete all the other JsonObjects I created (besides the first one) in my array list.

Comment: Requesting all to not provide full answer to any assignment work, rather give hints.

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this...

```
public ArrayList<ColonialFive> parseColonialFive(String a1) {
    ArrayList<ColonialFive> data = new ArrayList<ColonialFive>();       
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(a1); 
    if (jArray != null) { 
       for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
        Gson gson = new Gson();                     
        ColonialFive col= gson.fromJson(jArray.get(i).toString(), ColonialFive.class);
        data.add(col);
       } 
    } 

    return data;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a1= "[{\"fly\": true, \"blond\": 42, \"tragic\": false, \"top\": \"Foo\"},{\"fly\": true, \"blond\": 42, \"tragic\": false, \"top\": \"Foo\"}]";
    ArrayList<ColonialFive> data = new ColonialFive().parseColonialFive(a1);

    System.out.println(data);   

}
```

for this I am using two jar files **gson-2.2.2.jar** and **json.jar**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
public ArrayList<ColonialFive> parseColonialFive(String a1) {
    ArrayList<ColonialFive> data = new ArrayList<ColonialFive>();       
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(a1); 
    if (jArray != null) { 
       for (int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){ 
        Gson gson = new Gson();                     
        ColonialFive col= gson.fromJson(jArray.get(i).toString(), ColonialFive.class);
        data.add(col);
       } 
    } 

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are retrieving the first object each time.

```
JsonObject thisAble = jsonArray.get(0).asObject();
```

Change the `0` to `i` there.

Comment: That will not fix the problem.